# comparing two DateTime values but only using the day and not the time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I have this short block of code that is checking a DateTime variable.

It looks like this:

```
DateTime launchDay = DateTime.Today;
// launchTime.Begin is a DateTime? type
if (launchTime.Begin == null || launchTime.Begin > launchDay) return NoContent();
```

The problem is, launchDay is 'today', which is apparently midnight?

So if my launchTime.Begin is, let's say 2pm....then that is greater(after) 'launchDay' because 'launchDay' is set at 12AM.

How can I compare the dates so that I know that they are on the same day and not worry about the time so much?

I only want it to return NoConent() if launchTime.Begin is null or launchTime.Begin is not on the same day as the launchDay.

Is there a way to do this without running into the issue I am coming up against?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DateTime` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1) consists of two components: The date component and the time component. When you only care about the date (but not the time), then the time component is usually set to the default which is 0:00:00 (i.e. midnight).

This is also explained on [`DateTime.Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=netcore-3.1):

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.

In order to work with dates, ignoring the time components, you can use the [`Date` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) which will basically copy your `DateTime` value while settings the time component to midnight.

This allows you to do such comparisons:

```
if (launchTime.Begin == null || launchTime.Begin.Date > DateTime.Today)
    return NoContent();
```

Comment: Thanks! I played around with Parse and ParseExact as another question answer I found but that didn't help.  So basically, I can do this? launchTime.Begin.Value.Date > launchDay.Date?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Yeah, that should work. Note that if `launchDate` is `DateTime.Today`, then it already has no time component. So accessing `Date` of it doesn’t change anything.